# Is there anyway to add data from multiple objects to an arraylist with a function inside the original class

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I have multiple objects from one class that I want to send data to the same list. I'm wondering if I could do this from a function inside of the class I want to send data.
I just want everything to end up in the same list.

It would look something like.

```
#include  <vector>;

class object {
public:
    int x;

    object(int x) {
        this->x;
    }

    void checkValue() {
        if (this->x > 5) {
            arrList.store(this->x);
        }
    }
};

class arrList {
public:
    std::vector <int> list;

    void store(int x) {
        list.push_back(x);
    }
};

int main()
{
    object* objs[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        objs[i] = new object(i + 5);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        objs[i]->checkValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: If all objects of a class needs to share a "thing", then it sounds like you want a `static` member variable.

Comment: `object* objs[4];` -- Off topic, but why do this?  You could have just done `object objs[] = {5,6,7,8};`.  If not that, then `std::vector<object> objs;` and then `for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { objs.push_back(i + 5); }`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this was just for examples sake. But I'll take note of that first bit

Comment: Simply passing a target `arrList` instance to the method as `void checkValue( arrList &StoreTarget )` can not be permitted? If not, where should the `arrList` instance come from?

Comment: I don't understand.  What's the difference between your `arrList` and `std::vector`.  Why would I use `arrList` when I can use `std::vector`?

Comment: @fana     I guess that would work lol. I just thought it might look cleaner if I had an object specifically for storing data and not have to pass a bunch of arguments through those functions. Maybe I'm overthinking things

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's  exactly what I needed! I need to look into static members more that's really helpful

Comment: If you need a `static` variable, then keep data race in mind with the design.